# Is it possible to approximate some PDE semigroups by explicit methods?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, semigroup-of-operators

I'm concerned with the numerical methods for the approximations of semigroup associated to following Cauchy problems (which typically involves unbounded operators):

$\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{du}{dt} + Au&  = & 0 \\
 u(0) &=& u_0.
\end{array}
\end{equation}$     (1)

When $A$ is an m-accretive operator, it is known [1] that, a solution $u(t)$ can be given by an exponential formula:

$
u(t) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} [(I + \frac{t}{n} A)^{-1}]^n u_0,
$ (2)

which can be seen as an implicit Euler discretization scheme in time for the Cauchy problem (1).

Question :

Is it possible for some operators A (typically a laplacian) to approximate the semigroup using an explicit scheme such as :

$U_{k+1} = U_k + hAU_k.$ (3)

Ref:
[1] Haïm Brezis "Analyse fonctionnelle et applications"

Comment: Shouldn't A appear somewhere in formula (2)? Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: @Giuseppe You are right. It should be $u(t) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} [(I + \frac{t}{n} A)^{-1}]^n u_0$.

Answer (score -1):

You can find some useful information in the manuscript:

> P. Csomós, A. Bátkai, B. Farkas and A. Ostermann,
> Operator Semigroups for Numerical Analysis 2013.